# Copy image to clipboard in Android

Tags: android, image, clipboard

I want to copy image to clipboard for all level of apis. For this I have found an answer from the below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

But it does supports from api level 11. But I want to do same functionality in lower versions (less then of api level 11) also. `ClipboardManager` is working in all the versions but `ClipData, ClipData.Item, and ClipDescription` are not working in lower versions.

So is there any way to do copy image to clipboard?

And also I want to copy image from my application and paste it into another application like in compose message. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But I want to do same functionality in lower versions (less then of api level 11) also.

This is not supported, sorry.

Comment: Okay thanks, is it possible to do copy image from my application and paste it in another application like in compose message.

Comment: @Ramakrishna: That is not supported prior to API Level 11, and I suspect that the vast majority of apps do not support it on any API level.

Comment: Yes. I am asking you I want to paste image in compose message from my application. For this i have kept uri of image in clipdata. When coming to compose message screen it was paste uri not image.

Comment: @Ramakrishna: Then whatever application has this "compose message" perhaps does not support pasting images.

Comment: Okay thanks, so there is no way to copy image from my application and paste it into another application(it may be compose message).

Comment: @Ramakrishna: *Some* apps may support pasting images on API Level 11+. Not all apps will, and I suspect that rather few do.

Comment: @CommonsWare if you know, I want to know the app name which supports copy the image to clipboard from the one app and paste it in another app. Would you please share this information.

Comment: @ShreyashMahajan these days, Gallery allows to copy image to clipboard and it can be pasted in Whatsapp, Messenger, etc.