# Copying Image from drawable to Clipboard Android

Tags: android, image, clipboard

I have searched SO quite a lot and found the below answer.
[Copy Image to ClipBoard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476241/copy-image-to-clipboard-in-android)

I want to copy an image from my app and paste it in messages or memos.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.xample.abc/drawable/e1");
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(),"Check it",uri);

            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Above is a code snippet but it is just copying the uri Text i.e("android.resource://com.xample.abc/drawable/e1") not image from drawable folder.
Seemingly there is no way to copy the image using this code or method. I am quite stuck in it. Is there any way to copy an image from our application or custom keyboard?
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: I have read all the documentation and know it all before but not able to came up with a solution

Comment: Please mention the reason of down vote too, so that next time it wont happen.

Comment: @AsadAndyDev Have you found the solution yet?

Comment: @TOP android sdk don't let us copy image but we can perform it in iOS hope so in coming API levels android give this functionality too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Bitmap drawableicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
ClipboardManager mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
 Uri imageUri =getImageUri(YOURACTIVITY.this,drawableicon);
    ClipData theClip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "Image", imageUri);
    mClipboard.setPrimaryClip(theClip);
```

//get uri from the bitmap

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: Not working at all, It is just copying the path in text format and pasting it too

Comment: Tested on Android 13, it's working as expected, bitmap can be pasted in any app by GBoard.